# Display a popup once in front page

Tags: 7

Does any one know a good module I can use to set a nice popup (supporting html) on the front_page when a user visit the website for the first time??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zerolab is right! If disclamer module is not good for you, also try [Splash](http://drupal.org/project/splash) ([Splashify](http://drupal.org/project/splashify) on D7)

Comment: thanks, I have just installed it and it's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4):

You could give the [Disclaimer module](http://drupal.org/project/disclaimer) a try. It is quite easy to setup and can be used on any page.

Comment: I had some trouble using Disclaimer but I have found another module in Disclaimer related project and I used [it](http://drupal.org/project/splash), it works fine, thanks :)

Comment: glad you found a good solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another minimal candidate is [Tinybox](https://www.drupal.org/project/tinybox)

It is stripped down to the essential basics. Still it allows to choose which content type to display (node ID, Content Type or Views).